# html/css responsive 3-column layout - stack right column below left column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to get the right column of a 3 column layout to move below the left column on smaller screens. Right now the right column moves in the correct direction except that it hangs below the middle column.

I created this basic simulation of my issue. Note the middle column will always be longer than the left and right columns as shown here.

```
<style>
  .container {
    max-width:1280px;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .leftsidebar {
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin-top:15px;
  }

 .middle {
    width:57%;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:800px;
    margin-top:15px;
  }

 .rightsidebar {
    width:20%;
    background-color:orange;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:15px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="leftsidebar">left</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="rightsidebar">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution but I doubt you need float on your flex items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't accomplish that with Flexbox, unless setting fixed height's all over.

Here is a solution that combine Flexbox with `float`, and use a media query to swap between the two, when on narrower screens.

*Note, when using percent based width combined with fixed margins, it can at some point cause the item to wrap. Use CSS Calc to avoid that, as showed in the answer.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.leftsidebar, .rightsidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.rightsidebar {
  background-color: orange;
  clear: left;
}

.middle {
  width: calc(60% - 30px);          /*  calc for margin  */
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  height: 800px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
  .leftsidebar, .rightsidebar {
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
  .middle {
    width: calc(80% - 30px);          /*  calc for margin  */
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftsidebar">left </div>
  <div class="middle">middle </div>
  <div class="rightsidebar">right </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked out great since I need to keep flexbox to use "order" to rearrange the columns when it gets down to a single column.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up only with old good floats, no flexboxes at all. If you don't have to use flexboxes and you are interested, with pretty light hustle it might look like this (snap point is 700px):

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width:90%; 
    height:200px; 
    margin:0px auto;
}
div > div {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
.leftsidebar {
    width: 20%; 
    height: 200px;  
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.middle{
    width:56%;  
    margin: 15px 2% 0%;  
    height:415px; 
}
.rightsidebar {
    width: 20%; 
    height: 200px; 
    margin-top: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    div > div:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
        width: 33%;
    }  
    div > div:nth-of-type(2n) {  
       float: right;
       width: 65%; 
       margin-right: 0%;
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="leftsidebar">left </div>
<div class="middle">middle </div>
<div class="rightsidebar">right </div>
</div>
```